# Php exec() and pandoc in server production

Tags: php, nginx, exec, pandoc

When I try `<?php exec('/usr/bin/pandoc file -o file.pdf'); ?>` no file is created.
All formats works except the pdf format.

I think the problem is about the configuration server (debian 7 + nginx) and the function `exec()`.

Whereas this command /`usr/bin/pandoc file -o file.pdf` works in a terminal.

Thanks for your help

Same problem as [PHP shell_exec wait for script to done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524063/php-shell-exec-wait-for-script-to-done)

I have this problem with the logs: `pandoc: PATH: getEnv: does not exist (no environment variable)`

Comment: This almost always comes down to a permissions error.

Comment: I have already tested test this command with `su www-data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try `exec("pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex --from=markdown -s -S -o /tmp/pandoc.pdf --toc /tmp/pandoc > debug.log 2>&1");` to debug because nothing errors appear.

The log file show the PATH is not defined. I think because it's www-data who executes this script. I must define this global var.

So I try to define the env var PATH with `PATH=/usr/bin: pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex --from=markdown -s -S -o /tmp/pandoc.pdf --toc /tmp/pandoc` and it's works! :-)

It's also possible to define this var in /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite.com for a nginx server (or equivalent with apache) with

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    [...]
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.socket;
    fastcgi_param PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/your/path;
}
```

See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1587